# How to count empty input as an else

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

Im new to python and taking a class. Below's my code. My problem is at the very last line I want it so that if someone simply presses enter it will count as if someone made an input other than (1/2/3 or 4) which would basically reply with the last elif and restart the question. But at the moment it gives me this:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing.
```

Can anyone help?

```
def menu_loop():
    ans = True
    while ans:
        print("""
        1. My freedom awaits me, give me my blade!
        2. I've never fought before, might you help me?
        3. I have already forsaken freedom, I will fight till the death.
        4. Fighting is for the wicked. I refuse to fight.

        Press enter to quit
        """)

        ans= input("What would you like to do now?")
        if ans == 1:
            main_loop()
            break
        elif ans == 2:
            instructions_loop()
            break
        elif ans == 3:
            gauntlet_loop()
            break
        elif ans == 4:
            print("\nMen... come relieve this man of his life.")
            time.sleep(2)
            end_game_loop()
            break
        elif ans == '': 
            print("\nDo you not speak Latin, slave?")
```

Thank you, I found the answer thanks to Christian. I guess the site I got instructions from was on Python 3 and I'm on 2 (it's for a university assignment). It's working now, thanks lots!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 2 then change:

```
ans = input("What would you like to do now?")
```

to:

```
ans = raw_input("What would you like to do now?")
```

`raw_input` returns a string while input returns an `integer` this was changed in python 3, in 3 there is only `input` and it returns a string

so if you are using python 2 change it to `raw_input` then call your other conditions like this:

```
if int(ans) == 1:
    main_loop()
    break
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped quite a bit. I changed the input to raw_input because I am indeed using python 2(.7). When I added the int part though, the thing broke so instead I just put the numbers inside quotation marks and everything is working smooth now. Very much appreciated :D

Comment: yes you can do that too, Im glad i could help :) good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 0):

Change the last elif condition to `elif not ans`

```
def menu_loop():
    ans = True
    while ans:
        print("""
        1. My freedom awaits me, give me my blade!
        2. I've never fought before, might you help me?
        3. I have already forsaken freedom, I will fight till the death.
        4. Fighting is for the wicked. I refuse to fight.

        Press enter to quit
        """)

        ans = input("What would you like to do now?")
        if ans == 1:
            main_loop()
            break
        elif ans == 2:
            instructions_loop()
            break
        elif ans == 3:
            gauntlet_loop()
            break
        elif ans == 4:
            print("\nMen... come relieve this man of his life.")
            time.sleep(2)
            end_game_loop()
            break
        elif not ans: 
            print("\nDo you not speak Latin, slave?")
```

Edit: The answer is for python 3.
For python 2.7, use raw_input instead of input, and accordingly use int(ans) or string literals.

Comment: Did you test this on Python 2 or just Python 3?

Comment: @RayToal python 3.
On python 2, you need to change the `input` function to `raw_input`, and the `ans` then changes to `int(ans)`

Comment: @GOAT You might be having python 3 as well. Try doing a `python3 --version` in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

use `raw_input` instead of `input`. `input` will try to evaluate the input, evaluating an empty string raises an error. `raw_input` doesn't evaluate, just gives you a string. See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x).

```
def main_loop():
    pass
def instructions_loop():
    pass
def gauntlet_loop():
    pass
def end_game_loop():
    pass

next_loop_func = {
    '1': main_loop, 
    '2': instructions_loop, 
    '3': gauntlet_loop,
    '4': end_game_loop,
}
def menu_loop():
    while True:
        print("""
        1. My freedom awaits me, give me my blade!
        2. I've never fought before, might you help me?
        3. I have already forsaken freedom, I will fight till the death.
        4. Fighting is for the wicked. I refuse to fight.

        Press enter to quit
        """)

        ans = raw_input("What would you like to do now?")
        if ans in next_loop_func:
            next_loop_func[ans]
        else: 
            print("\nDo you not speak Latin, slave?")


menu_loop()
```